# How can I make a transparent image opaque in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, png, transparency, bufferedimage

For a Java program ("regular" program, not Applet and/or Android etc.), I have PNGs with transparency which are to be loaded and drawn atop other pictures, which is working perfectly fine. Now, for the case that there is no other picture below them (the determination of whether that is the case is not an issue, the respective code is already workingly implemented), I want them made opaque, but not in the sense of simply setting a background color; since the png source files concerned are fully colored, just with reduced opacity (alpha value) on them, it would, I guess, be no problem to simply increase the opacity of all the colors to 100%, I just don't know the commands to do it. Preferred and so far targeted way of doing it is by having them drawn in a BufferedImage, then modified respectively, but as said: How?

TLDR: images from .png with <100% opacity (same value on whole pic), how to make opaque in Java, preferrably with BufferedImage or even simpler

thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: (a simple brute force method to do it would of course be to simply draw the image multiple times atop itself and use it like that, but resorting to something like that is, I guess, unnecessary, or is it) EDIT: actually, that seems quite a good solution...

Comment: As well as I understand your description, which is 'not much', it is as easy as creating a `BuferedImage` of `TYPE_INT_RGB` the same size as the PNG, and painting the PNG to it.  That will produce the image on a black BG.  To change the BG color, simply set the color of choice to the `Graphics` instance and call `fillRect(..)` before drawing the image.

Comment: like I said, what I want is precisely *not* the transparency to be filled in with whatever background color, but the opacity/colors of the transparent picture itself amplified to opacity; for now, I went with the solution as in my previous comment; anyway thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `RescaleOp` to scale the alpha component all the way to opaque:

```
float[] scales = { 1f, 1f, 1f, 0f };  // R, G, B, A
float[] offsets = {0f, 0f, 0f, 255f};   // R, G, B, A
RescaleOp rescaler = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);
BufferedImage opaque = rescaler.filter(original, null);
```

See [this Java 2D tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) for more info.

Comment: In my case I actually had to use `float[] offsets = {0f, 0f, 0f, 255f};`